ChatOrUserPicker modal window in telebot API
Is there any functionality in the telebot framework that would allow me to show up a modal window with chat selection when the inline button in the telegram bot is pressed, so that the user selects a user to forward some message to?

Solution 1
You can open a pop-up window to select chat or user. But, for your bot to be able to send or forward a message to them that particular user has to initiate the chat.
You can make use of the KeyboardButtonRequestUsers or the KeyboardButtonRequestChat to pick open the chat/user picker. Once a user/chat is selected the bot will receive a service message with the selected chat information.
I'm pretty sure you're looking to send some message to the selected user or chat. To send a message to the user, the user must initiate the chat. To send a message to the selected chat, the bot must be a member of the chat with message sending permission allowed.

Solution 2
The other way around is, I would go for a Inline Button with InlineKeyboardButton with the switch_inline_query_chosen_chat property set. When this button is pressed initially the user will be requested to select a chat that satisfies your conditions with the passed SwitchInlineQueryChosenChat object. You can also set the query to be automatically typed in the input field. Now, your bot will receive the inline query and hence you can have your bot's user to send some particular message to the chosen user through your bot.
Hope this helps.
